# linux command pipe with python "-c" flag

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to do a string printing with python -c flag, e.g.
`python3 -c "print('Hello World')"`

So now I wanna substitute an argument with pipe, e.g. `echo "Hello World" | python3 -c "print($1)"`

the pipe is to take output from previous command and take it as input to next command, if I am not wrong, this is possible? But I think I got syntax error which I cannot find any source of this

I also bumped into [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739066/python-pipes-and-the-c-option-in-the-command-line) previously asked, but the solution required python imports and .py file depends on how we run this, I understand but I just wanna get it in a line of command in linux shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is always single line then you should be able to harness [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function for example

```
echo "Hello World" | python3 -c "print(input().upper())"
```

would output

```
HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: wow, nicely done, just a quick question, what if the input could be binary? such as ```cat ./test.bin | python3 -c "print(input())"```